# UICollectionViewCells hiding behind headerView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Using UICollectionView with custom headers. Strange thing happening is custom cells hiding behind header cell. Below is code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let reusableview = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CalendarHeaderView", for: indexPath) as! CalendarHeaderView
    
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
        
        reusableview.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 40)
         //do other header related calls or settups
        reusableview.headerLabel.text = "Month"
        
        return reusableview
        
    default:  fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.bounds.width / 7.0
    let height = width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
   
}
```

[image: Header image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
        
        /// PROBLEM
        reusableview.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 40)
        
        return reusableview
        
    default:  fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

You are not supposed to set the frame of `UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader`. `UICollectionView` does all of that for you. You just need to tell it how big (`CGSize`) it needs to be.

You can tell `UICollectionView` about this size via following method -

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 40)
    }

}
```